# svn client to group commits by time range

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, svn-client

1. Is there any SVN `Client/Eclipse` plugin which could let the user see all his/her commits during a time range (per day, etc)? Since our CI doesn't support grouping the commits by tasks, how can I do the above thing by myself?
2. Is there a way to see all my commits per day in `Eclipse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. None of Subversion clients allow *internal filtering* by commit-author (AFAIK) (but `svn log | grep USER` will work)
2. `svn log` in core have support for dates as revision parameters (see `svn help log` /-r "{DATE}"/ and [Revision Dates](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates) topic in SVN Book /with **special attention** to warning "Is Subversion a Day Early?"/)